# WPF: Main thread not frozen on binding

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, modal-dialog, sta

There are:

- two ListViews
- several libraries (imported by using MEF)

Both lists need to get information from a library (one gets it on Loaded event, another - by binding with ItemTemplateSelector), but if there are several libraries with the same Metadata and different versions, dialog "Please choose version to be used" is shown.

The problem is that UI is not blocked when dialog is called with ShowDialog() method. Setting dialog's Owner does not help. 
So, when window is loaded, there are two "Please choose version to be used" non-modal dialogs.

How can it be fixed?

Comment: Do not implement this with bindings. Instead add some logic in the `Shown()` event or `Loaded()` event

Comment: I need to set individual DataTemplate for every ListBox's Item. Can I do it programmatically? (DataTemplate type is not known in advance, depends on Item)